# Execution of fluent regex

Tags: regex, api, fluent

We tried to run the following code :
fluentRegex package contains following java files:
RegularExpressionBuilder.java
RegularExpressionBuilderBase.java
InvalidTokenException.java
SingleCharMatcher.java

Codes in the above java files are taken from the following given link:
http://code.google.com/p/fluent-regex/source/browse/trunk/src/com/googlecode/fluentregex/?r=8

CODE:

```
import fluentRegex.*;

import java.util.regex.Matcher;

import java.util.regex.Pattern;

 public class CheckRegex
   {

public CheckRegex(){
String name = "Alen";
     RegularExpressionBuilder regEx =regExp().atLeastOne(anyOf().singleChar(',').whitespace());
  Pattern p = Pattern.compile(regEx.ex());
  Matcher expMatcher = p.matcher(name);
  String st=regEx.ex();
  System.out.println(""+st); 
 if (expMatcher.find())
{
  System.out.println("Month is: ");
}
else
{
    System.out.println("else part!");
}    }  
public void main(String[] args)
     {

    new CheckRegex();
}}
```

This code is giving following error:

```
C:\Users\Chitrangada\Documents\docs\DSL-Final yr project\code>javac CheckRegex.j
ava
CheckRegex.java:12: cannot find symbol
symbol  : method anyOf()
location: class CheckRegex
         RegularExpressionBuilder regEx = regExp().atLeastOne(anyOf().singleChar
(',').whitespace());
                                                              ^
CheckRegex.java:12: cannot find symbol
symbol  : method regExp()
location: class CheckRegex
         RegularExpressionBuilder regEx = regExp().atLeastOne(anyOf().singleChar
(',').whitespace());
                                          ^
```

2 errors

Please reply back soon with a possible solution

Regards,

DSL team

Comment: Tab characters and HTML do not mix well. Either convert tabs to spaces or indent each line with an extra four spaces at the start to preserve indentation.

Answer (score 1):

You can't just call these methods from your class. The method `regExp()` and `anyOf()` seem to be static methods from the `RegularExpressionBuilder` class. So you'd call them like this:

```
RegularExpressionBuilder regEx = 
  RegularExpressionBuilder.regExp()
    .atLeastOne(RegularExpressionBuilder.anyOf().singleChar(',').whitespace());
```

So you seem to be creating the pattern `[\s,]+`, which compared to that long winded code snippet is much clearer, even for someone not familiar with regex, IMO.

You could import all static methods from `RegularExpressionBuilder` by importing:

```
import static com.googlecode.fluentregex.RegularExpressionBuilder.*;
```

and you *can* then do:

```
RegularExpressionBuilder regEx = 
    regExp().atLeastOne(anyOf().singleChar(',').whitespace());
```

And one more thing: your `main` method should be made static:

```
public static void main(String[] args) { 
    // ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Java doesn't allow for free functions, only methods. Thus the calls to `anyOf()` and `regExp()` are illegal. Looking at the linked source code, `RegularExpressionBuilder` has static nullary [`anyOf()`](http://code.google.com/p/fluent-regex/source/browse/trunk/src/com/googlecode/fluentregex/RegularExpressionBuilder.java?r=8#132) and [`regExp()`](http://code.google.com/p/fluent-regex/source/browse/trunk/src/com/googlecode/fluentregex/RegularExpressionBuilder.java?r=8#10) methods. Perhaps you meant:

```
RegularExpressionBuilder regEx =
    RegularExpressionBuilder.regExp().atLeastOne(
        RegularExpressionBuilder.anyOf().singleChar(',').whitespace()
    );
```

There may be other problems with the code; this one is merely what immediately leapt out.